# why is my emacs yanking the wrong text?

Tags: emacs

running emacs 22... on ubuntu 9.04, fresh install.

When I copy a region of text via C-w (clipboard-kill-ring-save) then yank it back with C-y (clipboard-yank) it pastes random stuff, from some other buffer that isn't even open.

It was working fine earlier today and I haven't changed my emacs config.

Any ideas why this is suddenly happening/ how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: also note that this behavior persists even if I kill/restart emacs.

Comment: Have you tried starting emacs with the -q option to skip init files?  You might also want to see if you can reproduce the problem in a non-window mode emacs session (i.e. emacs -nw).

Comment: I restarted my machine and the problem went away...for a while. It started again this afternoon after using emacs all day without problems.

Even stranger, if I repeatedly C-y, it will yank the same incorrect text a number of times, then move on to some other random text numerous times, and so on.

Note that this is a new machine with a new Ubuntu 9.04 install. I had copied my .emacs and all my extra elisp stuff from my old machine. I never had this problem before, using the exact same config for years.

Comment: @ataylor - The problem didn't show up with emacs -nw. Event weirder, the problem went away after I ran emacs -nw, even in other emacs X sessions that previously had the problem.

hurrrdurrr...

Answer (score 1):

C-w is (kill-ring) - you should use M-w for copy. The appearance of random text in the kill-ring is most unlikely. It might be helpful for you to monitor the value of the symbol kill-ring(C-x C-e after it in any buffer) after M-w or C-w to determine if it's properly updated.

Comment: "The appearance of random text in the kill-ring is most unlikely." But not completely unlikely; I sometimes will get the last two kills when I perform a single yank (or, since I'm using EmacsW32, when pasting from the clipboard in an external app). It's really weird.

Comment: The problem is the same (when it happens) for both C-w (cut) or M-w (copy).

C-x C-e just brought up the emacs debugger, but there was nothing regarding the symbol kill-ring.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a day or two since I posted this, the problem has gone away. Don't know why it started happening or why it stopped.